# How to avoid slow for(): loops, when using Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, for-loop

```
for i in range( 1, len( df ) ):
    if df.loc[i]["identification"] == df.loc[i-1]["identification"] and df.loc[i]["date"] == df.loc[i-1]["date"]:
       df.loc[i,"duplicate"] = 1
    else:
       df.loc[i,"duplicate"] = 0
```

This simple for loop runs really slow when processing a dataframe of a big size.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more specifics: what is "slow" and what is a "big size".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a vectorized approach instead of looping:

```
df['duplicate'] = np.where((df.identification == df.identification.shift())
                           &
                           (df.date == df.date.shift()),
                           1,0)
```

Comment: Great, this is really what I wanted, huge improvement in running time, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just checking if values are duplicated. In that case, you can use

```
df.sort_values(by=['identification', 'date'], inplace=True)
df['duplicate'] = df.duplicated(subset=['identification', 'date']).astype(int)
```

Comment: The sorting was already done, but your suggestion does work well too, thank you.